# Вычислить среднее число учитывая отклонения

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, формулы

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть массив чисел, например

```
[603, 21, 25, 23, 2, 57, 19, 148, 160, 182, 501, 60, 26, 21, 25]
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы алгоритм каким-то образом подобрал все числа для нового массива так, чтобы убрать все отклонения и найти среднее между оставшимися числами. (формат формулы любой, но в приоритете Python, Excel)

*Мои попытки:*

1. Как я пробовал, это сделал условие, что если отклонение следующего числа больше 10%, не добавлять, иначе добавить в массив - тут возникла 1 проблема, в примере выше, так как берется для начала операции 1 число, получается так, что за основу берется число 603, из чего следует, что в итоге средняя всех чисел массива и будет 603, потому что нету в массиве больше чисел, подходящих под условие.
2. Дальше чтобы выйти из этой ситуации, сделал сложнее, сделал создание "категорий", работало так, 2 цикла с условием проверяло, подходит ли число к текущей категории, если нет, создается новая и в итоге выходило что-то типо этого 
   `[[603], [21, 23, 19, 21], [25, 26, 25], [57, 60], [148, 160, 182], [501]]`
   , дальше сортировал по длине и выбирал самый длинный массив.

В итоге ни тот вариант, ни тот в конце концов не подошли, может формулы квадратичного отклонения или среднего геометр. значения как-то использовать, идей пока что нет.

Comment: Покажите пример хорошего результата

Comment: Ну вроде как подход-то стандартный... считаем среднее, считаем доверительный интервал, считаем максимальное отклонение, если оно больше доверительного интервала - отбрасываем максимально отклоняющееся значение и повторяем. PS. Я вообще не понимаю - в начале вроде как просто массив, а потом в способе 2 всплывает позиционная зависимость...

Comment: @MBo хороший пример, это в итоге, например, по тому, что я показал выше должно быть среднее где-то 22, тоесть числа которые там значительно больше 20 и меньше должны отброситься, иначе среднее арифметическое сильно будет неправильное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Решение с использованием модуля Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/covariance/plot_mahalanobis_distances.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-covariance-plot-mahalanobis-distances-py) - подобные методы часто используются в задачах машинного обучения и обработки данных (набор входных данных должен быть двумерным, поэтому в случае простого списка его придется преобразовать к таблице с одним столбцом).

```
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.covariance import EmpiricalCovariance, MinCovDet

a = np.array([603, 21, 25, 23, 2, 57, 19, 148, 160, 182, 501, 60, 26, 21, 25])

# reshape 1D array to 2D matrix
X = a.reshape(-1, 1)
```

Получилась таблица с 15 строками и одним столбцом:

```
In [70]: X.shape
Out[70]: (15, 1)
```

Считаем [`Minimum Covariance Determinant (MCD)`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet.html#sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet):

```
robust_cov = MinCovDet().fit(X)
```

находим аномалии, используя [MinCovDet().mahalanobis()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet.html#sklearn.covariance.MinCovDet.mahalanobis):

```
In [73]: a[robust_cov.mahalanobis(X) > 1]
Out[73]: array([603,   2,  57, 148, 160, 182, 501,  60])
```

"хорошие" данные:

```
In [74]: a[robust_cov.mahalanobis(X) <= 1]
Out[74]: array([21, 25, 23, 19, 26, 21, 25])
```

---

**UPDATE:**  при сильно коррелированных данных, данный метод может выдать следующую ошибку:

```
In [267]: robust_cov = MinCovDet().fit(X)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:677: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  self.dist_ /= correction
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:716: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  mask = self.dist_ < chi2(n_features).isf(0.025)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\robust_covariance.py:720: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  location_reweighted = data[mask].mean(0)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py:73: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:1128: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  avg = a.mean(axis)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\covariance\empirical_covariance_.py:81: RuntimeWarning: Degrees of freedom <= 0 for slice
  covariance = np.cov(X.T, bias=1)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:3109: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  c *= 1. / np.float64(fact)
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:3109: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  c *= 1. / np.float64(fact)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
```

В этом случае надо явно указать `support_fraction`

Пример:

```
In [285]: robust_cov = MinCovDet(support_fraction=1).fit(X)

In [286]: a = np.array('16 2 8 3 2 3 3 3 4 12 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 4 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 6 2 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 4 3 4 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 2'.split()).astype(int)

In [287]: X = a.reshape(-1, 1)

In [288]: robust_cov = MinCovDet(support_fraction=1).fit(X)

In [289]: a[robust_cov.mahalanobis(X) <= 1]
Out[289]: array([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

In [290]: a[robust_cov.mahalanobis(X) > 1]
Out[290]: array([16,  2,  8,  2,  4, 12,  4,  4,  6,  2,  2,  2,  4,  4,  4,  4,  2,  2,  2])
```

Comment: а можно уточнить что за mahalanobis(X)? Поставил библиотеку, все хорошо до этого момента, ругается что такого метода вообще нет, если знаете, то было бы здорово

Comment: @100РОЖЬ, какая у вас версия scikit-learn?

Comment: с этим разобрался вроде, редактор ругается, но код вроде исполняется, странно, но reshape теперь все ломает, если число есть двухзначное и обычное, выходит так [[ 3] [16]], и выходит ошибка ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'). Тоесть получается, надо от пробелов избавиться и вроде оно заработает да?

Comment: @100РОЖЬ, `.reshape(-1, 1)` нужен только в том случае если у вас входные данные в виде списка/вектора. Можете привести пример данных на которых ломается код?

Comment: [16  2  8  3  2  3  3  3  4 12  3  3  3  3  4  3  3  3  3  3  4  3  3  3
  3  3  3  3  3  3  6  2  3  3  2  2  3  3  3  4  3  4  3  3  4  3  4  3
  3  3  2  2  3  3  3  2], это кстати нормальное вообще отображение? это после np.array() оно стало таким, изначально обычный список с теми же данными

Comment: @100РОЖЬ, это Numpy при выводе на печать "красоту" навел... Попробуйте так `print(np_array_variable.tolist())`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75186/discussion-between-100-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться [этим решением](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16562028/5741205):

```
import numpy as np

def reject_outliers(data, m = 2.):
    data = np.array(data)
    d = np.abs(data - np.median(data))
    mdev = np.median(d)
    s = d/mdev if mdev else 0.
    return data[s<m]
```

Пример:

```
In [20]: l = [603, 21, 25, 23, 2, 57, 19, 148, 160, 182, 501, 60, 26, 21, 25]

In [21]: reject_outliers(l)
Out[21]: array([21, 25, 23,  2, 57, 19, 60, 26, 21, 25])

In [22]: reject_outliers(l).mean()
Out[22]: 27.9
```

или так (для `mu = 1`):

```
In [25]: reject_outliers(l, 1)
Out[25]: array([21, 25, 23, 19, 26, 21, 25])

In [26]: reject_outliers(l, 1).mean()
Out[26]: 22.857142857142858
```

Графическое представление:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

pd.Series(l).plot.kde(grid=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pd.Series(reject_outliers(l)).plot.kde(grid=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pd.Series(reject_outliers(l, 1)).plot.kde(grid=True)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS [также советую ознакомиться с методами нахождения аномалий в модуле Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#id1)

Answer (score 1):

Ничего удивительного, что у вас не получились те "лобовые" методы, которые вы попытались использовать.

Дело в том, что вычисление среднего, потом среднеквадратичного отклонения, потом ДИ сработают корректно только тогда, когда данные вашей выборки будут распределены по нормальному закону. Попробуйте построить гистограмму своего массива и увидите, что ваше распределение далеко от нормального. Можно очень приближенно его считать экспоненциальным, но это еще доказать надо.

В любом случае, рекомендую не изобретать велосипед, а ознакомиться с теорией. Раздел называется "выявление аномалий" (иногда еще говорят "обнаружение выбросов"). В рамках DataScience похожие задачи также решают в кейсе, который связан с "очисткой исходных данных". Методы и средства решения таких задач  проработаны достаточно детально на многие реальные случаи.

Хочу обратить внимание, что в зависимости от того, какова прикладная постановка задача - методы и подходы могут быть различными - это крайне важно, потому как единого, "канонизированного" метода нет и быть в данном случае не может.

Литературы более чем достаточно. Будут вопросы - спрашивайте.

P.S. Поскольку все-таки велосипед продолжают изобретать, попытаюсь  упростить жизнь изобретателям, дополнив свой предыдущий ответ.
Вот хорошая и не сложная статья, как это все сделать "по науке". Правда, стоит обратить внимание, что прямо в первых строках там указано, что описывается "один из" множества методов. При желании, можно ознакомиться и с другими.
http://mycroftbs.ru/grabbs/

Comment: +1 за *«единого, "канонизированного" метода нет»*